# Postgres query to convert stringifyed json object to jsonb object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

let say that the json object is > { "foo": "bar"}
after stringyfing i got > "{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }"

how can I get back the orginal json object using UPDATE sql query?

[image]

i'm aware of that it's a bad DB architecture it was designed by another engineer before me, that's why I would like get back the original json data and then alter the column to jsonb

**Update:** 
please be aware that I'm looking for an answer to do that with only sql query and without any involving of programming languages like javascript.. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this same issue by doing some regexp replaces.  You might not need the where clause, but in my case, I had a bug that started to stringify the JSONB column so only some of my data needed this change applied.

```
update your_table 
    set text = 
        jsonb(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(text::text, '"$', ''),  '^"+', ''), '\\"', '"', 'g')) 
    where text->>'foo' is null;
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do `to_json('{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }'::text)`

so it would be something like

`update yourtable set yourjsoncolumn = to_json(yourjsoncolum::text)`

Comment: I got the following result using your answer: ""{ \\\"foo\\\": \\\"bar\\\" }""

sql: select to_json('{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }'::text);